# Why SAP crystal report load very slow only first time?

Tags: crystal-reports

Can anyone know why SAP crystal report load very slow even with simple report only first time then after it load quickly and what is the solution to overcome with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying the crystal report using the .net platform, the first time the form loads it will be slow because of the time it takes the JIT compiler to generate the machine code.

We ended up running a report when the main program starts so that subsequent reports are faster.

1. The report opens minimized so that you don't see it.
2. There is a flag that is checked so that as soon as the report is loaded it is closed from .net.
3. This is a report that has nothing more than a bit of text on it.  No connections to the server or anything

[More in depth explanation of what happens with JIT compilation](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.winforms/2004-10/msg00208.html)

[SO answer about when JIT compilation happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398760/jitted-machine-instructions-at-program-restart)